# Earth's distance from the sun affects nuclear medicine

Tags: alternative-medicine, astronomy

Does the Earth's distance from the sun affect the efficacy of nuclear medicine?

Comment: Presumably connected to claims that there have been observations of seasonal variation in measured halflives. See links in [this answer from Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/48712/520) and [this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/75077/520). The claims are generally for very small effects and are not widely accepted, and at least some preprints never achieve peer reviewed publication.

Comment: ... What exactly is "nuclear medicine" ?

Comment: @Shadur - [Nuclear medicine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_medicine) in a nutshell, anything that uses radioactive substances in diagnosis or treatment. You might have heard of nuclear imaging which is part of it and uses radioactive tracers that bind to organs for imaging purposes.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but here we should see some demonstration of notability such as a lint to a specific version of the claim.